# Нужно удалить из текущего файла пустые строчки из текста и записать его в новый файл на Java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



class Laba14 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int i;
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;


        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream("C:/a/source.txt");
            fout = new FileOutputStream("C:/a/destination.txt");

            do {

                i = fin.read();
                if (i != -1)
                    fout.write(i);

            }
            while (i != -1);
        } catch (IOException ехс) {
            System.out.println("Oшибкa ввода-вывода: " + ехс);
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (fin != null)
                    fin.close();
            } catch (IOException ехс) {
                System.out.println("Oшибкa при закрытии входного файла");
            }


            try {
                if (fout != null) fout.close();
            } catch (IOException ехс) {
                System.out.println("Oшибкa при закрытии выходного файла");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

читаем файл, удаляем пустые строки, записываем то что осталось

```
List<String> text = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/a/source.txt"));
while (text.contains("")) text.remove("");
Files.write(Paths.get("C:/a/destination.txt"), text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/a/source.txt"));
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:/a/destination.txt")
) {
    String s;
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
        if(!s.trim().isEmpty()){
            fw.write(s);
        }
    }    
}
```